# How can one intentionally starve kernel processes?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, deadlock

I'm new to kernel programming and was thinking on how one can make single process running which means that other kernel processes should die or get starved. What can be optimal approach to this situation. I'm working on kernel version 2.6.38.

Comment: Maybe "named kernel thread" is a more appropriate name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while (1);` should do a good job of starving other processes - especially if you first disable interrupts.

Comment: @mah - my system crashes on using while(1)

Comment: @Dhruv - starving other processes can have that effect on systems; the disabling of interrupts is the clincher. If your real intention is to place the kernel under heavy load, don't disable interrupts and replace `while (1);` with code that will at least occasionally yield the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Disable CPU quotas.  Raise your process priority to the highest possible. Create as many for(;;) threads as there are cores.  Raise their priority to the highest available.  Set them running.

Not so sure about Linux, TBH.  Such an activity on Windows needs the power switch for recovery.

Comment: Without grsec, I've had fork bombs eat enough kernel pid tables to require the power switch too.

Comment: @Martin James - Hey thanks for answering, but where to make these changes in kernel sched.c?

Comment: On Linux, kernel will soon deprioritize. Effective priority is a heuristic function of, among others, the amount of processing time a thread hogs.